# Create async function to call result later in express route

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I have to get an Excel file from Box.com via API and convert the Excel to JSON. Later on this JSON will be rendered with Express and Handlebars.

I created the following function to fetch the Excel/JSON:

```
let getExternalFile = async () => {
  const stream = await client.files.getReadStream('123456789');
  const external = await fs.createWriteStream('/external.xlsx');
  stream.pipe(external);
  let finished = await external.on('finish', async () => {
    const excel = await excelToJson({
      source: fs.readFileSync(external.path),
      header: {
        rows: 1
      },
      columnToKey: {
        A: "edate",
        B: "esource"
      },
      sheets: ['Sheet1']
    });
    console.log(excel);
    return excel
  })
}
```

My problem now is that I do not know how to resolve the pending Promise when I do this:

```
let testData = getExternalFile();
console.log(testData); // Promise { <pending> }
```

I would download multiple files with such a function and would like it then to store in in my variable to pass it later to my express route.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('stories.ejs', {
        msg: "Welcome to stories.ejs", 
        odata: odata, 
        edata: edata,
        ...
    });
});
```

Do I have to wrap it in an anonymous async function to call it?

Comment: If it's a Promise that is returned, can't you add `.then()` and add your code there?

Comment: Well I would have multiple `then()` inside each one because I have mutliple files, would'nt I?

Comment: `getExternalFile().then((external) => { console.log(external);})` returns also `undefined`

Comment: you already are using async/await so await this promise also. `await getExternalFile()`

Comment: @mrks You're not returning anything from `getExternalFile()` and I think if you have multiple Promises, you can store them in an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to resolve.

Comment: you need to return the `finished ` variable also.

Comment: @AZ_ I can not do this unless I wrap everything in an anonym. function.
If I return `finished` I get the `Stream Object` returned instead of the JSON from the Excel file (`const excel`)

Comment: define and return the `excel` in the outer scope.

Comment: You cannot await an event handler (`external.on(...)`). You can only await promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async`/`await` is not the panacea for all things asynchronous. They were designed to work only with Promises. Specifically, `async`/`await` does not work with event emitters. The correct implementation of `getExternalFile` should be:

```
let getExternalFile = async () => {
  const stream = client.files.getReadStream('123456789'); // no await here
  const external = fs.createWriteStream('/external.xlsx'); // no await here
  stream.pipe(external);

  let finished = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    external.on('finish', async () => { // cannot use await here
      const excel = await excelToJson({
        source: fs.readFileSync(external.path),
        header: {
          rows: 1
        },
        columnToKey: {
          A: "edate",
          B: "esource"
        },
        sheets: ['Sheet1']
      });
      console.log(excel);

      resolve(excel);
    })
  });

  return finished; // return the promise so you can await it later
}
```

All non-promise functions (I will not call them non-"async" because it will confuse people with the difference between async asynchronous functions and non-async asynchronous functions because people sometimes use "async" to mean asynchronous and sometimes to mean the "async" keyword which are promise generating functions)... I digress... all non-promise functions don't work with `await`. This includes things like event emitters `x.on('some_event' ... )`.

For such cases you will need to wrap them in `new Promise()` to convert them to Promises.

Now that we've re-written the above function we can simply await the result:

```
app.get('/', async /* <--IMPORTANT */ (req, res) => {
    let testData = await getExternalFile(); // use await here!!

    // ...
});
```

If you have multiple awaits then the function may be slow:

```
app.get('/', async /* <--IMPORTANT */ (req, res) => {
    let testData = await getExternalFile();
    let testData2 = await getExternalFile2(); // SLOW!

    // ...
});
```

If you can get away with it you can execute the async functions in parallel:

```
app.get('/', async /* <--IMPORTANT */ (req, res) => {
    let testDataArray = await Promise.all([
        getExternalFile(), getExternalFile2()  // FAST!
    ]);

    // ...
});
```

---

#### Epologue: Errors

In real code you should catch errors on code you are awaiting to prevent your server from crashing:

```
app.get('/', async /* <--IMPORTANT */ (req, res) => {
    try {
        let testData = await getExternalFile(); // use await here!!

        // ...
    }
    catch (err) {

        // ...
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can use a middleware such as [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler) to catch async errors.

Comment: Nice! And don't forget handle errors in express route callbacks

Comment: @ArturKhrabrov Yeah, should really be in try.. catch blocks or use a promise catching middleware